# Styling A Link Button Using CSS Across Browsers

Tags: html, css

UPDATE #2: I have solved almost all my issues bar the one major one.  With the same structure and CSS IE7/6 displays each a with 100% width of it's container.  I need this to  no happen.  Besides that everything else is fine.  Can anyone enlighten me?

UPDATE:  Should Look Like This

[image]

I have the following html page (detailed below).  It simply renders 2 styled buttons from the links.  My problem is IE6 & 7 renders it differently than Firefox, Safari, IE8 and Chrome that all render it correctly.

I have been banging my head against the wall for a day now trying to make it work in IE6/7.  Can anyone offer advice as to what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>

      .niw-button {
          background:      #1f81c0 url(niw-btn-gradient-normal.png) repeat-x;
          border:          none;
          color:           #fff;
          display:         inline-block;
          font-weight:     bold;
          margin-right:    6px;
          min-width:       95px;
          padding:         2px;
          text-decoration: none;
      }

      .niw-button:hover {
          background: #5e698f url(niw-btn-gradient-hover.png) repeat-x;
      }

      .niw-button > .niw-button-contents {
          border: 1px solid #73b1da;
      }

      .niw-button > .niw-button-contents:hover {
          border: 1px solid #99a1bc;
      }

      .niw-button .niw-button-icon {
          background-position: center;
          background-repeat:   no-repeat;
          float:               right;
          height:              25px;
          width:               27px;
      }

      .niw-button .niw-button-text {
          height:         25px;
          line-height:    1.5em;
          padding-left:   5px;
          padding-right:  27px;
          text-align:     center;
          text-transform: uppercase;
      }

      .right-align {
        float:right;
      }

      .niw-icon-cancel {
          background-image: url(niwater_cancelIcon.png);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a class="niw-button right-align" href="#">
      <div class="niw-button-contents">
          <div class="niw-button-icon niw-icon-cancel"></div>
          <div class="niw-button-text">Cancel</div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="niw-button" href="#">
      <div class="niw-button-contents">
          <div class="niw-button-icon niw-icon-cancel"></div>
          <div class="niw-button-text">Cancel</div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Now that I understand your image:

Just make your `<a>` elements block elements with display:block and put some kind of span inside of them to hold the icon. Or you could make the whole thing an image...

Comment: Actually I can't do that.  The main container (in ym case the a) has a gradient background).  The contents then needs to set an icon as it's background - it can't be one with one a set to block.

Comment: Yes it can. Build the a with the gradient background. Put a span inside of it with the icon as the background. That's it.

Comment: Then you lose the inner border which is a requirement.  I sort of resolved it by fixing the width of all buttons... should be acceptable for the customer. (finger crossed)

Comment: I still don't see why you can't go with a simple flat image that changes on mouseover.

Comment: Because we have a large number of buttons each with differing Icons and text, each with variable widths.  I tried the static approach and if I had to have 2 images per button (normal and hover) it would be like going back to the HTML of the early 90's

Answer (score 0):

IE6/7 doesn't support `display: inline-block`, IE6 doesn't support the child (`parent > child`) selector. So you probably should look into those points in your css...

Comment: The parent > child issue sorted out a good few issues.  Totally forgot about that thanks.  But the main issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I actually don't get correct rendering in IE8, which is what I address below:

For a start, you should put the `<a>` elements inside the  elements rather than the other way round.  Block level elements shouldn't really exist within inline elements.  e.g.

```
  <div class="niw-button-contents">
      <div class="niw-button-icon niw-icon-cancel"></div>
      <div class="niw-button-text"><a class="niw-button right-align" href="#">Cancel</a></div>
  </div>


  <div class="niw-button-contents">
      <div class="niw-button-icon niw-icon-cancel"></div>
      <div class="niw-button-text"><a class="niw-button" href="#">Cancel</a></div>
  </div>
```

This fixes the positioning for me but there is a subsequent loss in styling.  I haven't tinkered with the CSS to correct that yet but it should be straightforward.  Secondly, you have an awful lot of classes to deal with a straightforward issue.  Arguably you should only need one class in the outer `div` to identify what's happening inside, and then your CSS can descend from there.

Comment: Then the entire button can't be clicked.  Which breaks the solution slightly.

Comment: It can be if styled correctly - the inner div for displayed icon is unnecessary as this style can be applied to the link itself, with appropriate padding all round and no margin on the a element.  For the inner border, a span could be used on the link text.

Comment: I tried that approach but it seems to cause the same amount of issues in IE6/7

Answer (score 0):

Just one tip for a resource to the button/link problem in general:

http://mezzoblue.com/archives/2008/09/17/anchor_butto/

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually confused myself. How are they supposed to look? If you don't let us know what you're intending to do, it's very difficult to fix the problem.